# Difference between logistic regression with binary output and classification

Tags: classification, bigdata, logistic-regression

Hello all big data / statistics experts,

I am in a big data class right now and was wondering if anyone currently utilizing these techniques in practice could explain to me the practical differences between logistic regression and classification in terms of feature control and output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much. Logistic regression with binary output is a kind of classification (remember: "regression" in this case is a misnomer).

The result of logistic regression can be interpreted as a probability, and you use a threshold to classify if a given instance is positive or negative.

There's another problem with your questions: *classification* is a broad class of techniques. Are you perhaps trying to compare logistic regression with another algorithm you saw?